# Can attacker escalate its privileges if he has access a web Application running with www-data

Tags: web-application, ubuntu, mod-security

I have deployed an opensource web Application named "opencart" it has simple password. My question is can attacker login my system and escalate privileges if he login web application and even know the password of mysql database.

Comment: As with any software if there are known unpatched vulnerabilities then an attacker could exploit them, or if there are unknown vulnerabilities then an attacker may discover them and develop an exploit. The specifics of opencart vulnerabilities are probably better suited for a specific dedicated discussion board. All the best :)

Comment: There are many (known/patched/unpatched/unknown) priveledge escalation problems in all kinds of (system or application) binaries and frameworks. So while you absolutely must try to close them down by patching and hardening you also must not assume they don't exist. Things tomespecially look out for a suid binaries and System services running as different users.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is can attacker login my system and escalate privileges if
>   he login web application and even know the password of mysql database.

**Fast Answer : Yes...**

## WebApp

I suppose you mean the attacker has access to the cms admin **backoffice**.

Attacker could try to achieve [ACE (Remote Code Execution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) / [RFI (Remote File Inclusion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability)

- [Upload a php shell embedded in an image](https://github.com/jgor/php-jpeg-shell)
- Upload & Install a malicious Opencart Extension (to grant shell access) 
  [image: opencart backoffice : extension uploader]
- Upload a php shell (using other methods)

## MySQL

A shell can be uploaded also...

If the attacker has the database credentials and the database allows remote connections, then it can perfectly perform much evil with a simple mysql client remote connection, specially if the credentials have high privileges.

If the database only accepts local connections it could also happen, example : attacker manages to upload a shell by other means, and connects from the local machine through his shell with the database credentials.

This could even happen in scenarios where the attacker doesn't know the database credentials but manages to find a good sql-injection in the webapp.

**WARNING :** If the webapps database has been setup with root / full privilege account, a **SQL Injection** could mean  **gameover** (no need for the attacker to escalate privileges)

[Article : SQLMAP Shell upload [SQL Injection]](http://www.hackingarticles.in/shell-uploading-in-web-server-using-sqlmap/)

Comment: but password of root user for mysql is different from password of root user for OS. Moreover, Web App is running with www-data user. He can also get access in this case too.